# how to implement paytm AllinOneSdk in ios i am able to run it in android but i'm not getting exact steps for ios in react native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, flutter, paytm

Add the latest paytm All-in-one SDK to the ios app created by react-native(Drag and Drop).
I have cloned [project](https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_iOS_All_in_One_SDK/tree/master/Swift/AppInvokeSDK.framework) as per step 1

but i am confused about drag and drop where to drag and drop

2. Info -> URL Types : Add a new URL Type that you’ll be using as the callback from Paytm App (URL Scheme: “paytm”+”MID”). Example: paytmMid123
   -i'm not getting what is exact structure im not able to see in xcode as per given screenshot
3. where to put plugin classes

what i did is added sdk in  General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content
LSApplicationQueriesSchemes added
URL types added like this
[image: URL TYPEs]

and Add `AllInOneSDKSwiftWrapper.m` added in ios=>myproject directly.
in `Appdelegate` added given code
but getting very long error after running react-native run-ios

```
................
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening myproj.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace myproj.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme myproj -destination id=757187B2-AD08-4F7C-8FEF-BEC2FC8CB43A

note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'myproj' from project 'myproj')
    cd /Users/arjun/Documents/myproj/myproj-react/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh

Ld /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.app/myproj normal x86_64 (in target 'myproj' from project 'myproj')
    cd /Users/arjun/Documents/myproj/myproj-react/ios
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-ios9.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift-5.0/iphonesimulator -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Branch -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCrashlytics -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Permission-Camera -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Permission-Microphone -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTTypeSafety -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCAsyncStorage -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCCheckbox -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCMaskedView -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNDateTimePicker -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBApp -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBCrashlytics -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBDatabase -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNGestureHandler -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNPermissions -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReactNativeABeep -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNScreens -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-agora -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-branch -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-image-picker -L/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-safe-area-context -F/Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/arjun/Documents/myproj/myproj-react/ios/Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS -F/Users/arjun/Documents/myproj/myproj-react/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/arjun/Documents/myproj/myproj-react/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -filelist /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myproj.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myproj_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -lBranch -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreDiagnostics -lFirebaseCrashlytics -lFirebaseDatabase -lFirebaseInstallations -lFolly -lGoogleDataTransport -lGoogleUtilities -lPermission-Camera -lPermission-Microphone -lPromisesObjC -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNCCheckbox -lRNCMaskedView -lRNDateTimePicker -lRNFBApp -lRNFBCrashlytics -lRNFBDatabase -lRNGestureHandler -lRNPermissions -lRNReactNativeABeep -lRNReanimated -lRNScreens -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lYoga -lc++ -lglog -licucore -lleveldb-library -lnanopb -lreact-native-agora -lreact-native-branch -lreact-native-image-picker -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lresolv -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AdSupport -framework AgoraRtcEngineKit -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreML -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework JavaScriptCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework VideoToolbox -framework WebKit -framework iAd -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/myproj.app-Simulated.xcent -lPods-myproj -framework AppInvokeSDK -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myproj.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/myproj_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.app/myproj
ld: framework not found AppInvokeSDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'react-native-image-picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'AgoraRtcEngine_iOS' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 7.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'RNReactNativeABeep' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 8.0 to 13.6.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/arjun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myproj-gyrpkplvcxphvnfmkqfdcisiqspl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/myproj.app/myproj normal x86_64
(1 failure)
```